# Conditional value in column to change a value in same row of another column

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

Suppose I have 2 tables, for this example, the inbuilt R dataset mtcars and iris.

What I want to do is pass a conditional argument for a column in mtcars, and based on that condition change a corresponding cell column in iris.

For example, if mtcar$mpg < 20 I want iris$Sepal.Width to be "NA" in the same row that the mtcars$mpg < 20.

Have:

```
First 5 rows of 
mtcars 

df1<-head(mtcars)
df1

                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2

First 5 rows of iris

df2<-head(iris)
df2

Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
```

Want:

```
First 5 rows of 
mtcars 


                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2

First 5 rows of iris

Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
5            NA         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
```

Preference for solutions/suggestions in BASE R not tidyverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
df1 <- head(mtcars, 5)
df2 <- head(iris, 5)

df2$Sepal.Length[df1$mpg < 20] <- NA
df2

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5           NA         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: this looks like what I want, I did not realize I could pass the conditional arguments in multiple datasets like you have done here.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replace`

```
df2$Sepal.Length <- with(df2, replace(Sepal.Length, mpg < 20, NA))
```